# Ember CLI - package.json & bower.json dependencies

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I work on an Ember CLI project that has Ember Data declared as a dependency in the the project's package.json and bower.json files respectively.  Two different Ember Data versions are declared.

Which dependency takes precedence and why must it be declared in two places?

```js
package.json

{
  "devDependencies": {
    "active-model-adapter": "1.13.5",
    "emberx-select": "1.1.4",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
    "broccoli-funnel": "^0.2.3",
    "ember-cli": "0.2.7",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.3",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-html5-validation": "0.0.18",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.6",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.13",
    "ember-cli-rails-addon": "0.0.11",
    "ember-cli-sass": "4.0.1",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.18",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2",
    "shared": "../shared"
  }
}
```

```js
bower.json

{
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.13.2",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "1.13.4",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.4",
    "ember-qunit": "0.3.3",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.15",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1",
    "bourbon": "~4.2.3",
    "bitters": "~1.0.0",
    "neat": "~1.7.2"  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependency in Bower determines which version is used in the built app. I believe the npm package is just there for the development tooling.